# Smallest PIC which the TCP/IP stack can be implemented

Tags: pic, ethernet, tcp-ip

What is the smallest (size) PIC with internal oscillator available which the TCP/IP stack can be implemented (and used) successfully? Also, what is the smallest (size) PIC with internal oscillator and Ethernet stack implemented?

Comment: You should define your question little bit more. For example by smallest, do you mean smallest footprint, cheapest or you refer to amount of ram?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're going to use [Microchip's TCP/IP Stack](http://www.microchip.com/pagehandler/en-us/technology/ethernet/tools/softwaretools.html), the PIC18 is the 'lowest-end' family of PICs that the software stack supports.

On their [Ethernet page](http://www.microchip.com/pagehandler/en-us/technology/ethernet/products/picmcus.html), Microchip recommends the [PIC18F97J60](http://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/Devices.aspx?dDocName=en026439). It has MAC and 10BASE-T PHY integrated.

> - IEEE 802.3 compatible Ethernet Controller
> - Fully Compatible with 10/100/1000Base-T networks
> - Integrated MAC and 10BASE-T PHY
> - Up to 128KB Flash
> - 8 KB Ethernet Buffer
> - Support for Unicast, Multicast and Broadcast packets
> - Programmable wake-up on multiple packet formats,including Magic    Packet®, Unicast, Multicast, Broadcast,specific packet match or any
>     packet
> - 64/80/100-Pin TQFP Package

Comment: As far as I have seen both PIC18 and PIC32 families have the same minimum size, 10mm x 10mm x 1mm. Is there any other encapsulation with smaller size?

Comment: @Frederico So you're interested in the physical size of the chip (package). I couldn't say.

Comment: The chip may have an internal oscillator, but I think you need an external 25MHz crystal to get the required clock for the Ethernet controller.

Comment: @Robert that might be true but there is no sense put an internal oscillator that can't provide all the features that the microcontroller has

Answer (score 2):

You may want to explore the [ENC28J60](http://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/Devices.aspx?dDocName=en022889).  It's an external chip from the PIC that handles all the Ethernet.  It interfaces to the PIC via SPI bus.  Just choose a PIC that has enough flash and RAM for the TCP/IP Stack.  You can download and compile to a simulator to see how much space things take.

Answer (score 1):

On the link provided by m.Alin you can see in the right bottom corner a button named `See all  Ethernet PIC MCUs` which lead to [here](http://www.microchip.com/ParamChartSearch/chart.aspx?branchID=145) where you can see different characteristics, including packaging in the most right column. By the look of it, the smallest PIC32 with Ethernet are 64/QFN 64/TQFP

Comment: I couldn't find any one smaller than 10 mm x 10 mm x 1 mm, am I missing something?

Comment: Not sure if it is any help, but 64QFN have 9x9x0,9 mm. Albeit 10% shorter side it is still only a 1 mm difference and I have a feeling you looking for something much smaller.

Comment: as small as possible. I found the ENC28J60 which has a 5.3 mm of length and other encapsulations with 6x6 mm. I just don't know exactly what I can do with them, I mean, I just need ethernet, I don't need any other functionality of a PIC, so maybe that's the smallest CI I can find